# ERROR 1060 (42S21): Duplicate column name 'eid'

Tags: mysql

I am trying to figure out why I'm getting a duplicate column name in this query. I feel like I am properly prefixing my search terms and shouldn't be getting this error. Please advise.

Model

```
Emp(eid:integer, ename:varchar, age:integer, salary:integer)
Works(did:integer, eid:integer)
Dept(did:integer, managerid:integer) //managerid is foreign key to eid
```

Query

```
CREATE VIEW Manager AS
SELECT e.eid, e.ename, e2.eid, e2.ename
FROM Emp AS e,
    Dept AS d
        LEFT JOIN Emp AS e2 ON d.managerid = e2.eid;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try some ALIAS in your fields. See Below:

```
CREATE VIEW Manager AS
SELECT 
      e.eid AS eid1, 
      e.ename AS ename1, 
      e2.eid AS eid2, 
      e2.ename AS ename2
FROM Emp AS e,
    Dept AS d
LEFT JOIN Emp AS e2 ON d.managerid = e2.eid2;
```

Comment: Your welcome. At least accept it as answer to close the question.

Comment: I will once the time frame passes.